# How to simulate a carriage return in an input field that grows with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a basic HTML form with a text area input field.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <textarea class="text-input" rows="1" cols="20" name="describe_your_project">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </textarea>
</form>
```

As the user types in this field as they type to the end of the space for this input field, I'd like for the `textarea` to basically drop down a line like a carriage return without the default scrollbar showing up.

I've seen this in basecamp and other programs, but not sure if this is a jQuery function or CSS3 value.  Any insight would be great.

Comment: Try out this [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/jaz303/jquery-grab-bag/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.autogrow-textarea.js) -- `$('textarea').css('overflow', 'hidden').autogrow();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's post above.  I tried several of the options above and different browsers behaved different (Chrome was having problems with the options above).  I did a little more research and came across this one:

https://github.com/jevin/Autogrow-Textarea

Hope it helps someone in the future...thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.text-input').bind('input keyup',growme);
function growme() {
    var $this=$(this);
    $this.data('lineheight',$this.data('lineheight')||$this.height());
    if (this.scrollHeight-1>$this.height()) $this.height($this.height()+$this.data('lineheight'));
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/FAH9H/)

or simplier

```
$('.text-input').bind('input keyup',growme);
function growme() {
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
}
```